# different results when I encode a character to base64

Tags: php, base64, chr

When I encode a character to base64, I get different results depending on the the way I pass the character:
For example, I want to encode `chr(128)` => €

1.passing the result of `chr()`: `base64_encode(chr(128))` => 'gA=='
2.passing the character directly: `base64_encode('€')` => '4oKs'

Why are the results different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chr(128)` returns a 1 byte character which represents the €-sign, therefore the base64 encoded string encodes ony 1 byte (80 hexacdecimal = 128 decimal):

```php
echo bin2hex(base64_decode('gA=='));
```

> 80

On the other hand, in `base64_encode('€')` the '€' is a unicode string, and the encoded result contains 3 bytes, the unicode representation of the Euro-sign:

```php
echo bin2hex(base64_decode('4oKs'));
```

> E282AC